# variant of Fermat's last theorem for exponent 3

Tags: number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Three variable, third degree Diophantine equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14721/three-variable-third-degree-diophantine-equation)

Has anyone seen the proof that $x^{3} +y^{3}=3z^{3}$ has no solutions in Eisenstein integers? 
I have tried to mimic the proof for $x^{3} +y^{3}=z^{3}$ having no solutions in Eisenstein integers and am stuck on the "hard case" of when $\lambda |z$ where $\lambda=1-\omega$ and $\omega$ is a primitive cubic root of unity. Thanks for any help you can offer.